# UICollectionViewFlowLayout.scrollingDirection change forces reload - Swift 4

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, rotation, uicollectionviewlayout

I am working on an app which is locked into portrait mode. Now we added rotation handle on pictures.

I have a `UICollectionView` with every cell taking full size of screen in order to show the picture in full screen. Thing is you can choose which picture you want to see before showing the full screen cell on the `FullPictureViewController`.

When you change the rotation of your phone, here's what happen:

```
    func rotatePictures(cell: NewsImageCell) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
        case .landscapeLeft:
            let newImage : UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cell.imageView.image!.cgImage!, scale: cell.imageView.image!.scale, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)
            cell.imageView.image = newImage
            self.layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
            cell.layoutSubviews()
        case .landscapeRight:
            let newImage : UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cell.imageView.image!.cgImage!, scale: cell.imageView.image!.scale, orientation: UIImageOrientation.left)
            cell.imageView.image = newImage
            self.layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
            cell.layoutSubviews()
        case .portrait:
            let newImage : UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cell.imageView.image!.cgImage!, scale: cell.imageView.image!.scale, orientation: UIImageOrientation.up)
            cell.imageView.image = newImage
            self.layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            cell.layoutSubviews()
        case .portraitUpsideDown:
            let newImage : UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cell.imageView.image!.cgImage!, scale: cell.imageView.image!.scale, orientation: UIImageOrientation.upMirrored)
            cell.imageView.image = newImage
            self.layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            cell.layoutSubviews()
        default:
            print("terminator")
        }
    }
}
```

Now, here is my problem: if I delete `self.layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal`, I can see my picture and rotate it, but the scrolling direction will stay locked at `.vertical`. But if I switch the `self.layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal`, the collectionView reloads its data source and then sends me back to item[0].

Anything related to the `scrollDirection` seems to send me back to the first item, while I'd like to keep the current item.

Any solution or work around to do it ?

Comment: Have you tried to use this method: 
`self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell), at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally, animated: false)` ?

Comment: I did try something like this but for some reason, it crashes sometime, even though I always check `cell != nil` before calling `rotatePictures`. I'll keep diging into it, maybe by keeping the index somewhere then scroll to that index, as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install this pod:

https://github.com/Krisiacik/ImageViewer

and pass your imageview object when you call this library method.